# Current increase for IO Expander/Level Shifter

Tags: mosfet, current, level-shifting, powermosfet, io

I’ve been designing a project recently that uses a level shifter/io expander. I’m trying to figure out the best way to go about increasing output current while still allowing the io to be bidirectional.

For example, I would use mosfets from VCC to the output of the IO but what would be the best way to avoid the mosfet when the signal comes the other way? The IO expander is rated for around 25 or 40mA? It’s not that important because it’s much less than the expected 140mA that may be drawn sometimes.

Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: IO expander's IOs normally configurable for only one direction i.e. input or output. Am I correct? So once you configure an IO for output then how can you use that IO for input as well?

Comment: Yes it goes both directions

Comment: I'm sure you don't expect it to happen automatically i.e. you need to manually "switch" the direction of the pin (e.g. stated in CL's answer).

Comment: You don’t have to switch the direction of the pin but you do have to select the pin

Comment: Actually, I looked at the datasheet again. You do have to use the third bit to state read or write but it makes no difference as the the pins will be changing at the same time. It’s not something that needs a quick input then output or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

To output a high signal, activate the P-channel MOSFET. To output a low signal, activate the N-channel MOSFET. To use the pin as an input, deactive both MOSFETs. (This is exactly how transceivers like the 74xxx245 work.)

Comment: Thank you. Although the 245 wouldn’t work with my situation I now have a better idea of where to go. I’ll have to use the same concept on a mutlicomponent basis